# Angular: How do I change value based on key value

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello so I'm getting a string value and I want to pass it to another function. So for example if I get 'eng' I want it to be 'en'. I don't want to use slice or if. I tried making an enum but that didn't work.

```
ngOnInit(): void {    
this.setLocaleDateFormat(this.translateService.currentLang);
    }

 setLocaleDateFormat(language: Languages): void {
    this.dateAdapter.setLocale(language);   } 

export enum Languages {   
'eng' = 'en',   
'slk' = 'sk',   
'cze' = 'cz',
 }
```

So I want to pass the value and based on some template change it to something else.
I'm getting eng but I want to setLocale to en for expample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you post, I believe `this.translateService.currentLang` will return 'eng'. I doubt this but going back to your question. Languages should not be an enum. It should be a constant object.

```
export const Languages = {
  eng: 'en',
  slk: 'sk',
  cze:  'cz',
};

setLocaleDateFormat(): void {
    this.dateAdapter.setLocale(Languages[this.translateService.currentLang]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of `language` is not `Language` which is `"en" | "sk" | "cz"`, but `keyof typeof Languages`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwKZQDJwgQwDaoAUe2+qAXIhjmAOYg62rICUiA3gFCKIQLJwCAOhK1CAcjSZSBRFDjiANIhK4CLANycAvp06owIALZUa9Rsw49E3cQdrjEAXkR2wS67eR4A1o5eSfso8thAAXqj+ruFKOnqgkLAIKOhYaqgAIjhQqABicABORtnEZgxMlD6oAJ5wwHLVAA6odaZ05cwslABucDAAJhzcKdLphNTtFsgA2nhlFgC6mjo2nFJpZFk5+UUlbg7LQA)

```
function setLocale(locale: Languages) {
  console.log('setLocale to', locale);
}

enum Languages {   
 'eng' = 'en',   
 'slk' = 'sk',   
 'cze' = 'cz',
}

function setLocaleDateFormat(language: keyof typeof Languages): void {
  setLocale(Languages[language]);
} 

setLocaleDateFormat('eng');
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need a reference object:

```
const map = {eng: 'en', slk: 'sk', cze: 'cz'};
```

Then you can use it in your code like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {    
    this.setLocaleDateFormat(map[this.translateService.currentLang] || 'defaultLocale');
}

setLocaleDateFormat(language: string): void {
    this.dateAdapter.setLocale(language);   
}
```